# Why won't my Djinn hang on to a +6 Demonbane?

Tags: nethack

Same Djinn, she has a +0 Unihorn, but if I give her the +0 uc Long sword that she has had for over 10k turns, she wields that until she finds a trice.  But, when I try to give her this high-powered artifact (or even just a blessed +6 RP LS), she just picks it up and puts it down (even when I whip her sword away and leave DB forever). The wiki says she should value Artifacts most, so what's going on here?  She is stone-resistant, so I get the trice thing. DB isn't intelligent, so a blast doesn't explain the aversion. She doesn't level up as fast as my V lord (who doesn't like any weapon), and I have some gauntlets of power that I can enchant up and give to her, as well as a few GL potions. Will any of this help?

Actually, I'm wondering... I always picture Djinni with a scimitar, would she prefer that weapon? She even drops my +7 Grayswandir, and I'm not going to give her my +7 Excalibur, or should I?

Comment: Weapon Intelligence causes a 4d10 blast to cross aligned users.  Unintelligent weapons can cause only a 4d4 blast.  Perhaps your djinni has sensitive hands...

Comment: And personally, I'd be much more willing to give up Excalibur than Grayswandir.  When enchanted to +7, Grayswandir is an end-game beast.

Answer (score 2):

A Djinn is neutral-aligned.  Demonbane is lawful.

[Cross-aligned unintelligent artifacts will still blast you one time in four](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Artifact_blast#Unintelligent_Artifacts).  Monsters don't like this, so although they will prefer an artifact weapon over any other weapon, they will refuse to pick up or wield a cross-aligned artifact.